# VueJs2+typescript - Unable to restrict private variable to get accessed in template

Tags: angular, typescript, vuejs2, access-specifier

I have worked upon almost all the `Angular2+` versions using `typescript`. I am bit new for `VueJs2`.

Since in `Angular` we keep `public` variables which can be used inside `HTML template` and `private` variables are mainly used for processing the information in `.ts` file.

Since `VueJs` is also quite similar and follow `Angular` syntax, however, I am unable to get this below behaviour of variable

In my `VueJS` with `typescript` and I am using `class` based approach, even when I marking a variable as `private` then also I am able to access it values directly in `Vue Tempalte` ? [CodeLink](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-river-8ci8y?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

How should I differentiate between `public & private` variables such that, I can keep my private variables for process/manipulate the data.

Whereas when we define `private` variable in `Angular` and try to access in `HTML` it gives us the error [CodeLink](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hzyppf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated
Thanks.

Comment: That's because `#private` is still a [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods) (without much support). In Angular, it's Angular that's stopping you from using it. If you choose to turn that flag off, you'll see that accessing a private property outside the class actually works (and the template is outside the class).  See current support [here](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_classes_private_class_fields).